# Clarity about Client Server web application over HTTPS

Tags: java, http, tomcat, https

I know the scope of this question is very large and its not appropriate to ask it here. But I don't know where to go.

I have a web application (client) + a web application (server). Both are working on tomcat on two different ports.

Now, I want the client to send and receive data to/from server using HTTPS/SSL, or in better terms, using a secured connection.

Need some guidance/clarity for this. Some questions that I have are:

1. Should I change some settings in TOMCAT so that my server runs on HTTPS ?
2. Should I make changes to client as well ?
3. How do I establish the connection via HTTPS ?
4. How do I know that data is transferred over HTTPS ?

Answer (score 0):

u should state the content of the jsp page to be "contentType/https"